# A stupid question on cohomology of sheaves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-cohomology

Let $X$ be a projective variety. Denote by $GL(n,\mathcal{O}_X)$ be the sheaf which associates to an open set $U$ the general linear group $GL(n,\mathcal{O}_X(U))$. Is  there any kind of addition operation (not necessarily commutative) defined on $H^1(GL(n,\mathcal{O}_X))$? I would think that the multiplication of the matrices should induce an operation on $H^1(GL(n,\mathcal{O}_X))$.

Comment: No there is no group structure. In general, if $G$ is a non-abelian group, $H^1(X,G)$ is just a pointed set.